# N1QL Ansi join using spring data couchbase on document id

Tags: spring, spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I'm trying to do a join using spring data couchbase.
The documentation has this [example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.ansijoins)

```
@Document
public class Author {
      @Id
      String id;

      String name;

      @N1qlJoin(on = "lks.name=rks.authorName")
      List<Book> books;

      @N1qlJoin(on = "lks.name=rks.name")
      Address address;
     ...
}
```

I need to do the same, except my model uses the document key:

```
@Document
public class Author {
      @Id
      String id;

      String addressId;

      //@N1qlJoin(on = "lks.addressId=meta(rks).id") this doesn't work
      @N1qlJoin(on = "lks.addressId=rks.id") //nor this
      Address address;
     ...
}
```

Comment: Found a bug, it is missing the tilde in the resolution if my bucket name contains slashes https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/couchbase/core/convert/join/N1qlJoinResolver.java#L52

Comment: Second issue, it's not implemented on the ReactiveCouchbaseRepositories

Comment: Or the RxJavaCouchbaseTemplate